# Pass data from PHP directly to DOM variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'd like to pass some data from PHP to JavaScript without JSON.
The reason is because I don't want the data been readable by anyone if clicks on view page source.

So, I have a PHP like

`print(<script type="text/javascript">a = "aaa";</script>);`

In my HTML code this will be

`<script type="text/javascript">a = "aaa";</script>`

I can remove this in the client side, after loading the variable. By for example with jquery

`$('script[type="text/javascript"]').remove();`

And after the DOM will not have anymore the script tag, but the variable a.

Later if I type to the console `window.a` will be `aaa`.

But i do not want to show the `<script type="text/javascript">a = "aaa";</script>` in my HTML source code. Is this possible, to pass the PHP variable directly to the DOM?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you want to hide script tag? What is wrong with it?

Comment: All I will say is, if you have something that you don't want an end user to see, like a user ID or whatever, then chances are your solution may not be the best and JavaScript to be a no-go, given that it's viewable to the end user and easily tampered with.

Comment: Why do need this security? Passwords etc. should be checked server-side, not via Java-Script.

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this, in case there's a better solution to your problem the Stack Overflow community can provide?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is a client-side language. Whatever you pass to it (by whatever means) will be readable by the end user.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Script DOM won't help, as "view source" shows the HTML code as it was during download. If that is what you are concerned about, you can fetch the variable via an AJAX once the DOM has been loaded.

(But it still is readable by anyone who can read JavaScript (an re-run the AJAX call), use Firebug or Wireshark. It really only helps against a simple "view source".)

Comment: @Répás Then you can send data to the document using cookies. Cookies data is not visible through "view source", but still visible by advanced users. But your script can remove the cookie after the cookie is used, so the data will not be easily visible by everyone.

Comment: @Karolis Neet. And can i make a cookie with the PHP, and handle the same with JavaScript?

Comment: @Répás This is how you can set cookies in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php And this is how you can handle cookies in JavaScript: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html

Comment: @Karolis Nah, too much data for the headers :D